# What is a named number?

Tags: r

I have a data structure that rstudio is identifying as a "named number" when I google this the results talk about named vectors but I don't see a mention of named numbers. Are they the same?

What is the best way to think about this? Is it a dictionary? A list of two lists?

My goal is to sort by the number and then get the names in order of magnitude.

`print(my_named_number)`

```
Baker Street       Charing Cross   Edgware Road (B)    Elephant & Castle 
           8.420070e-04                9.403936e-01                3.732567e-05                4.620485e-03 
             Embankment                   Harlesden          Harrow & Wealdston                Kensal Green 
           1.000000e+00                1.566635e-12                1.623611e-17                3.082285e-10
```

Apologies that this isn't reproducible, I don't know how to build a named number and the data I'm working with is the vector part of the list returned by `igraph:eigen_centrality(igraph_object)`

edit:

```
str(my_named_number)

Named num [1:4] 8.42e-04 9.40e-01 3.73e-05 4.62e-03
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "Baker Street" "Charing Cross" "Edgware Road (B)" "Elephant & Castle"
```

Comment: Use `str` on your object to provide a reproducible example

Comment: What about `v <- c(a=1, b=2, c=-1); names(sort(v))`

Comment: A "number" is always a vector in R. There are no scalar data structures as in other languages.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware of `str()` that's great. `names(sort())` works, why does `names(max(v))` return `NULL`?  Is it reasonable to say that a named number is a dictionary?

Comment: @Hugh_Kelley please have a look at my answer. Use `which.max`

Comment: @Hugh_Kelley [In theory, yes.](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A-level_Computing/AQA/Paper_1/Fundamentals_of_data_structures/Dictionaries) But there is no data structures called "dictionary" in R.

Comment: It is quite closed to a dictionnary. You can access by name like `v["a"]`. Vectors and lists can be named in R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution to access the names in order and the name of the maximum :

```
v <- c(a=1, b=2, c=-1)
names(sort(v))
> [1] "c" "a" "b"
names(which.max(v))
> "b"
```

Answer (score 4):

"Named foo" in the output of `str` just means your object is a vector of `foo`, with names attached to it.

```
x <- c(1,2,3)
names(x) <- letters[1:3]
str(x)
# Named num [1:3] 1 2 3
# - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "a" "b" "c"

y <- c("bar", "baz")
names(y) <- letters[1:2]
str(y)
# Named chr [1:2] "bar" "baz"
# - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "a" "b"
```